# Actualización en tiempo real de datos en Firebase y manejo de flip-cards con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde genero flip-cards para mostrar datos de una base de datos de Firebase. Usando la propiedad `innerHTML`, creo las tarjetas en función del número de pozos presentes en la base de datos. Las tarjetas se crean correctamente, pero me encuentro con dos problemas.

1. Actualización en tiempo real de datos: Cuando actualizo algún dato en la base de datos de Firebase, los cambios no se reflejan en tiempo real dentro del código HTML, aunque puedo ver las actualizaciones en la consola.
2. Problema con el script de las flip-cards: Estoy usando un script para manejar la animación de volteo de las tarjetas. Sin embargo, el script no funciona correctamente cuando hay varias tarjetas presentes. ¿Cómo podría modificar el script para que funcione para cada tarjeta específica de manera individual?

Este es todo mi codigo:

```js
function addCard() {
  var firebase = "https://sienapa-734e9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/data/pozos.json"
  var datos_pozo = new EventSource(firebase);
  datos_pozo.addEventListener('put', function(e) {
    var json = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(json);
    if (json.path == "/") {
      dbody = document.getElementById("container-flip-card-body");
      for (var key in json.data) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var h5_f = document.createElement("h5");
        var p_1 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_2 = document.createElement("p");
        var div_button = document.createElement("div");
        var h5_b = document.createElement("h5");
        var p_3 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_4 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_5 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_6 = document.createElement("p");
        var button = document.createElement("div");

        //Agregar las clases de cada elemento
        div.classList.add("flip-card");
        p_1.setAttribute("id", key);
        h5_f.classList.add("card-title");
        p_1.classList.add("card-text", "estado");
        p_2.classList.add("card-text", "electricidad");
        div_button.classList.add("d-grid", "gap-2");
        h5_b.classList.add("card-title");
        p_3.classList.add("card-text");
        p_4.classList.add("card-text");
        p_5.classList.add("card-text");
        p_6.classList.add("card-text");

        //Insertar valores por medio de innerHTML
        //var str = json.data[key].nombre;
        //var title_name = str.split(' ').join('');

        h5_f.innerHTML = json.data[key].nombre;
        //var estado = json.data[key].estado_pozo.estado;
        p_1.innerHTML = "<b>Estado:</b> " + json.data[key].estado_pozo.estado;
        //var electricidad = json.data[key].estado_pozo.electricidad;
        p_2.innerHTML = "<b>Electricidad:</b> " + json.data[key].estado_pozo.electricidad;
        div_button.innerHTML = `<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" formmethod="post"><i class="bi bi-power"></i></button>
                                      <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="flipCard()">Mas información</button>`;
        h5_b.innerHTML = json.data[key].nombre;
        p_3.innerHTML = "<b>Convenio:</b> " + json.data[key].convenio;
        p_4.innerHTML = "<b>Concesión:</b> " + json.data[key].concesion;
        p_5.innerHTML = "<b>Ubicación:</b> " + json.data[key].ubicacion;
        p_6.innerHTML = "<b>Información extra:</b> " + json.data[key].informacion;
        button.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="flipCard()">Regresar</button>';


        // Unir todo
        div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <img src="https://telegra.ph/file/c19f88650a45e2c393ceb.png" class="gota">
                ${h5_f.outerHTML}
                ${p_1.outerHTML}
                ${p_2.outerHTML}
                ${div_button.outerHTML}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <img src="/static/img/gotas.png" class="gota">
                ${h5_b.outerHTML}
                ${p_3.outerHTML}
                ${p_4.outerHTML}
                ${p_5.outerHTML}
                ${p_6.outerHTML}
                ${button.outerHTML}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
        //Agregar el contenido al HTML
        dbody.appendChild(div);

        document.getElementById(key).value = json.data[key].estado_pozo.estado;
      }
    } else {
      s = json.path.split("/");
      console.log(s[1]);
      console.log(json.data);
      document.getElementById(s[1]).value = json.data;
    }
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.titulo {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content_cards {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  color: #000;
  padding: 25px;
}

.flip-card {
  perspective: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.icon-switch:before {
  content: "\e9b6";
}

.gota {
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lista de Pozos</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/static/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="titulo">Lista de Pozos</h1>
  <div class="container-flip-card" id="container-flip-card-body">

  </div>

  <script>
    function flipCard() {
      var flipCard = document.querySelector('.flip-card');
      flipCard.classList.toggle('flipped');
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      addCard();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```